# Make Telerik Grid to show the number of records but display only a few at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

I have an MVC3 app with a Telerik grid control. When I call my web service, I only return 10 records at a time, but my user has 1100 total records. Of course I dont want to pull all 1100 records, I only want to pull 10 and when the user clicks on one of the paging button to show more, I go to the webservice and get the next 10 for that set.

```
  @(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
  .Columns(columns =>
   {
       columns.Bound(o => o.number).Width(100).Title("File #");
    })
     .Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(10))
     .Sortable()
     .Scrollable(s => s.Height(275))
     .Name("Grid")
     .Selectable()
  )
```

My problem is my Telerik control only shows 10 records with a max of 10, so there are no paging buttons at the bottom. So how do I set the max records of a Telerik grid but only show 10 (the paging size) at a time?

Comment: I found it  .Pageable(settings => settings.Total(30))
            .EnableCustomBinding(true)

Comment: if you have found an answer. Please post it as an answer and mark it so that it will be useful for others. Thanks!